# Do imports have to be at the start of program

Tags: import, dart

New dart user and I am wondering whether all my imports must be at the start of program or whether I call them after functions or inside them etc.

I seem to get an error saying `unexpected import` when the import isn't at the start ?

Is it something wrong with me or do dart import have to be at start.

## Example

```
import "dart:something"; // not a real import but you get the idea.
int dumb_function(int a, int z) {
    return a * z - (a * z); // what ever
}
import 'dart:something_else'; // that's what I want.
```

Comment: It's not clear why you think the import below `dumb_function` would have a different effect than if it were above it, but nothing like that is supported anyway.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : I needed it for something else and yes it would have a different effect. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Imports need to be at the top of a library file.

The only thing that can come before imports are a `library` statement or comments.

Comment: There are no exceptions or workarounds. What are you trying to accomplish?
You can't determine at runtime what to import and what not, this has to be defined statically to be available at compile time.

Comment: I will add an example explaining what I want to achieve